# Get the total score of players from only a recent number of matches in MySql

Tags: mysql, database, xampp

My MySql table named match_info roughly looks like this -

```
    match_no | player_id | score

       1     |  1        |  50
       1     |  2        |  12
       2     |  1        |  10
       2     |  2        |  14
       3     |  1        |  11
       3     |  2        |  30
```

The actual table contains a lot more data than this. Anyways for the sake of example, lets say this is the table  for now. What I want is to find the total score of each player for a select number of recent matches. For example say now I need to count only 2 recent matches. So only match no. 3 and 2 should be counted and my output should be -

```
player_id |  score
  2       |   44
  1       |   21
```

How can I do this? 
I tried the following -

```
SELECT player_id,SUM(score) as total_score 
FROM  match_info 
where match_no IN
(select match_no 
from match_info 
ORDER BY match_no DESC LIMIT 2)
group by player_id 
order by total_score desc;
```

However the error I encountered was-

> This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

So I can't use limit inside of "IN" sub-query. What alternative method may I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this query, It's Working as you expected.

```
SELECT player_id, SUM(score) FROM match_info m1 INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT match_no FROM match_info ORDER BY match_no DESC LIMIT 2) m2 ON m1.`match_no` = m2.match_no GROUP BY `player_id` ORDER BY `player_id`
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works like a charm :D ...  I did come up with a solution a while ago using MAX and comparison operators but your solution seems much better.

Answer (score 0):

You can try "join" vs a temp table with values you want to compare which will allow more query optimization.

Comment: tried but it didn't exactly work out. So not sure how to do it.